# What does bar plot compute in Y-axis in seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am visualizing the titanic dataset. I created 9 different age categories and was trying to visualize the age_categories vs Survived using a bar chart. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
age_cats = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df_train['Age_Cats'] =  pd.cut(df_train['Age'], 9, labels = age_cats)
sns.barplot(x = 'Age_Cats', y = 'Survived', hue = 'Sex', data = df_train)
```

[image]

I am not understanding what do the numbers  on the Y-axis represent?

My assumption is:

{n(Survived = 1)}/{n(Survived = 1) + n(Survived = 0)} or the ratio of people survived out of all people in that category. But how is seaborn calculating it?
Or do the numbers on the Y-axis represent anything else?

Comment: Did you take a look at the data? Generally sns.barplot should always put out the exact values you provided to the command. So the data should show the percantage of people who survived in the respective age category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bar plot shows the survival rate or percentage of people who survived.

E.g. in the age class 1 60% of all males survived. In the age class 7 less than 15% of all males survived.

This is calculated by taking the mean of the survival variable for that age class. E.g. if you had 3 people, 2 of which survived, this variable could look like `[1,0,1]`, the mean of this array is `(1+0+1)/3=0.66`; the bar plot would hence show a bar up to 0.66.